# How do I convert a numpy array to a tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an array `[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]` that I would like to convert to a tensorflow 'tensor' because I can modify tensorflow tensors with gpus. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tensorflow_tensor = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]])
```